# Linear search the given array to give required element index

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, linear-search

I have coded for linear search in Python3 but i am not getting required output.Below is the Problem:

> You have been given an array of size N consisting of integers. In addition you have been given an element M you need to find and
>
> print the index of the last occurrence of this element M in the array if it exists in it, otherwise print -1. Consider this array to be 1 indexed.
>
> Input Format: The first line consists of 2 integers N and M denoting the size of the array and the element to be searched for in the array respectively .
>
> The next line contains N space separated integers denoting the elements of of the array. 
>   Output Format Print a single integer denoting the index of the last occurrence of integer M in the array if it exists, otherwise print -1.
>
> SAMPLE INPUT
>   5 1
>
> 1 2 3 4 1
>
> SAMPLE OUTPUT
>   5

```
arr_len , num = input("Enter length & no to be search: ").split()
#num = int(input("Enter number to search: "))
list_of_elements = list(map(int, input("Enter array to search: ").split()))
found = False
for i in range(len(list_of_elements)):
 temp = list_of_elements[i]
 if(temp == num):
  print('--IF cond working--')
  found = True
  print("%d found at %dth position"%(num,i+1))
  break

if(found == False):
 print("-1")
```

Check here for my code (https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/FSYpglmfnz)

I didn't understand why **if** condition is not working inside **for** loop

Comment: Things like `if found == False:` should be expressed as `if not found:` for obvious reasons.

Comment: you are not finding `num` in the list of integers, because `num` is a string.  you need a `num=int(num)`.  Then you should start your search at the end of the list to find the last occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

To find the LAST position, you may search BACKWARDS and stop at the FIRST hit:

```
arr_len, num = 6, 1                    # Test Data
list_of_elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6]  # Test Data

pos = -1  # initial pos (not found)
for i in range(arr_len, 0, -1):        # 6,5,4,3,2,1
    temp = list_of_elements[i-1]       # adjust for 0-based index
    if(temp == num):
        pos = i # Store position where num is found
        break

print(pos)
```

Comment: This is the best answer as on average N/2 comparisons will suffice (assuming a uniform distribution), vs. N when going forwards.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
def find(digit, array):
   if digit not in array:
      return -1

   return max([i for i, x in enumerate(array) if x == digit]) + 1
```

The `+1` at the end as were told to consider the array 1 indexed.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr_len , num = input("Enter length & no to be search: ").split()
list_of_elements = list(map(int, input("Enter array to search: ").split()))
pos = -1  # initial pos (not found)
for i in range(0, int(arr_len)):
   temp = list_of_elements[i]
   if(temp == int(num)):
       pos = i + 1 # Store latest position where num is found

print(pos)
```